# Python: how to create a list from elements that don't meet a certain condition

Tags: python, list

I have a list of names as follows:

```
names = [ "Brian", "jake", "Jason", "Brad", "Tony", "jimmy", "Bobby", "Stevie"]
```

And I have to make a list called small_names which contain all the names which have 4 letters or less from the list above. I'm stumped.

My initial thinking was to use a while loop but it's not working.

Comment: please share the code snippet(s) that you have tried.

Comment: See [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

Comment: Cheers guys, think I'm sorted now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [filter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter):

```
small_names = filter(lambda n: len(n)<=4, names)
#equivalent to: small_names = [n for n in names if len(n) <=4]

print(small_names) # ['jake', 'Brad', 'Tony']
```

Using for loop:

```
small_names = []

for n in names:
    if len(n) <= 4:
        small_names.append(n)
```

Comment: Thanks Marcin, we haven't come across the filter command yet, is there another way using a while loop.

Comment: I wrote in the anwser: `small_names = [n for n in names if len(n) <=4]` Dont see a reason to use while for this. Better filter or list comprehension. But I added example with for loop.

Comment: Marcin,  Thanks a mill. Greatly appreciated! I'm making a lot of small mistakes. I presuming practice is the only way forward!

Answer (score 3):

I'd use [list comprehension](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk):

```
short_names = [name for name in names if len(name) <= 4]
```

Comment: @squaretrousers You are welcome. List comprehension is the most pythonic and most readable way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another answer you might want to try if you need to provide an explaination of how the code words and do not know what lambda is, or how filters work.

list = names
    for item in list:
        if len(item) <=4:
            print(item)

You can change item with shortNames if you wish, and thus be able to keep a name convention that makes sense to anyone looking at your code. item is too generic and could cost you points.

Good luck with the programming classes.

Comment: Cheers Michael! Yep I'm hoping someday I will know what lambda and filters are....I'll just have to stick with it!

Comment: @squaretrousers You don't need to use lambdas and filters if you have list comprehensions (in most cases).